# Algorithm to calculate the maximum of element in specific index PHP

Tags: php, sorting, data-structures

Is there a ready algorithm that keeps calculating the maximum of elements in the same index of multiple sorted arrays till we have maximum so for example:

`[1,3,6,7] [1,5,7,9] [1,5,9,10]`

first iteration the first element of each array i 1,1,1 so it completes to 2nd element

second iteration the secondelement of each array i 3,5,5 so it takes the second 2 arrays since they have the max

third iteration it compare 3rd element of chosen array so it compare 7 and 9 since 9>7 we will get the third array as result

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such function.

But you can do it by yourself

```
max(array_column($array,$index));
```

---

```
        $multi_array = array([1,3,6,7],[1,5,7,9],[1,5,9,10]);
        $index = 3;
        
        $max = current($multi_array[$index]);
        $max_index = 0;
        foreach($multi_array as $key => $array){
            if($array[$index] > $max){
                $max = $array[$index];
                $max_index = $key;
            }
        }
```

Comment: it helps me a lot, but how can i know from which arrays the maxes are from?